# Computing limits with natural log

Tags: calculus, limits

I have the following limit:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^nn^2$$

I know, for sure, that the limit is a finite number. I have tried the following method, but keep getting $\infty$:

- $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^nn^2 = L$$
- $$ \ln{L} = \ln\bigg({\lim_{x\to\infty} \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^nn^2}\bigg)$$
- $$ \Rightarrow \ln{L} = \ln{\bigg(\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^nn^2}\bigg)$$
- $$ = n\ln{\frac{2}{3}} + 2\ln{n}$$
- $$ \Rightarrow e^{\ln{L}} = e^{n\ln{\frac{2}{3}} + 2\ln{n}}$$
- $$ L = \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^n+n^2$$

This seems to be $\infty$. What am I doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I am looking for the simplest solution; I'm only a second year undergraduate.

Comment: At last step, should be $L=(2/3)^n \cdot n^2.$ [not $+$ as you have. Also you seem to have dropped lim somewhere, and do you mean $lim_{n \to \infty}$ at top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option:

$n \in \mathbb{Z^+}.$

Set $e^{-a}=(2/3)$, where $a>0$, real.

Then

$0 < \dfrac{n^2}{e^{an}} < $

$\small {\dfrac{n^2}{1+an+(1/2!)(an)^2 +(1/3!)(an)^3 +....} }$

$< \dfrac{3!n^2}{(an)^3} =\left (\dfrac{3!}{a^3}\right ) \dfrac{1}{n}.$

Take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Factor out $n$: $$n\ln{\frac{2}{3}} + 2\ln{n}=n\Bigl(\ln\dfrac23+2\dfrac{\ln n}n\Bigr)$$
and remember that $\ln x=o(x)$ near $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is going from the next-to-last time to the last line. The right side of the next-to-last line is the exponential of a sum--that is not the same as the sum of exponentials. It is not true that

$$e^{x+y}= e^x+e^y$$

So you cannot reach that last line. If you transform the next-to-last line properly, you just go back to your first line and have gained nothing.

A better approach is to use L'Hopital's rule. Your problem has the form $0\cdot\infty$, so transform it to a ratio. Use L'Hopital to find the limit of

$$\frac{n^2}{(3/2)^n}$$

Taking the derivative twice of numerator and of denominator gives a constant in the numerator and an exponential that approaches infinity in the denominator. Thus the limit is zero.

I'll leave the details to you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for a simple solution, here another approach using

- $0<q<1 \Rightarrow q^n \stackrel{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$ and
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}=1$

Let $a_n = \left(\frac{2}{3} \right)^n\cdot n^2$, then there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{2}{3}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2}\stackrel{n>N}{<}\frac{3}{4}$$

It follows that for $n > N$ you have 
$$a_n =\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}\cdot \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \cdots \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_{N}}\cdot a_N < \left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{n-N}\cdot a_N=C\cdot \left(\frac{3}{4} \right)^{n}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$